# activity.finish() is not stopped current activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created an android apps that using async task to call web service,
when authentication fail, user will stop current activity and redirect back to login page.

My problem is when user redirect back to login page, a toast text still showing, this toast text is under async thread onPostExceute() event.

any solution for this problem?

in the webService.cs

```
catch (UnauthorizedException ua) {
        Log.d(tag, ua.getMessage());
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
        if(condition a){
            intent.putExtra("toast_text", R.string.a);
        }else{
            intent.putExtra("toast_text", R.string.b);
        }
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(intent);
}
return null;
```

then in asyncTask.cs

```
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... parameters) {     
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) SingleFormActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (isConnected) {
        }

     return null;
}

public void onPostExecute(JSonArray result){
     if(result != null){
     }else{
          Toast.makeText(Something.this, R.string.b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

Comment: please show some code

Comment: It will be better if you quote the part of code here.

Answer (score 0):

you can Use

Create  Toast like

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

and   before  calling  `finish()` cancel toast using below  code

```
 if (toast != null )
      toast.cancel();
```

Comment: let me know your result

Answer (score 0):

In `onPause()` add below code

```
if(isFinishing()){
    if (toast != null || toast.getView().getWindowVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        toast.cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
Return request status from doInBackground.and show toast using that status in onPostExecute
may be there is any syntax error in this code.But i hope it help you

```
public class AsyncConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

private MyInterface mListener;


public AsyncConnectTask(Context context, String address, String user,
    String pass, int port, MyInterface mListener) {
               }

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ....
    return result;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (result == true) {
        //Show toast here
}else{

 }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when authentication fail, user will stop current activity and redirect back to login page.

with your above question, I assume you got two different activity (one for login and another for doing something also showing the toast message. If its correct then before showing the toast check if the activity is finishing if not then show the toast.

```
if(!isFinishing()){

 // show toast
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29